NetworkManager: connect both wired and wireless hotspot subnets
I have a Raspberry Pi with an LTE Modem hat, which I use as my primary router. It's broadcasting both a wireless hotspot and an ethernet connection, so that my wired+wireless devices can access the internet via the LTE modem hat.
The routing table looks like
<user>@RPI:~ $ ip route
default via 192.168.225.1 dev usb0 proto dhcp src 192.168.225.43 metric 100 
10.42.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.0.1 metric 101 
10.42.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.1.1 metric 600 
192.168.225.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.225.43 metric 100 

usb0 is the LTE Modem, eth0 the local ethernet connection interface, and wlan0 the local wireless connection interface.
As of now, my two local networks are unable to talk with each other. I enabled ip forwarding, net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 and I set up both connections using NetworkManager as shared, so that they can both access the same interface providing the internet (usb0):
ipv4.method:shared

I also have both local connections in the same firewall zone
nm-shared
  interfaces: eth0 wlan0

My question is, how can I allow my ethernet-connected devices to access my wireless devices? For example, I have a proxmox server running a Plex LXC, which access my router via a wired connection. How can I access my Plex instance from my laptop thats connected via a wireless connection?
